# How do I know how many connections are open while openning a website?

Tags: http, connection

I need to know when accessing to website how many connections are open.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the network tab inside your browser development console. You can see each request made in detail in there.

Comment: I saw it. There are hundreds of requests there, although in the link below it says the max connections open concurrently in a browser is limited to 8 or less, so I got confused.                                           http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.co.il/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that comment. Anyway: an alternative would be to track the log files on the server side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I edited my comment.

Comment: Just a question: how did you manage to edit your comment after such a long time? That should be limited to 5 minutes... Interesting.

Comment: About the limit: 1. are all those requests really fire in parallel, or are they pending? 2. the limit applies per domain, IIRC, not in total and 3. it might be that those limits have been raised in the mean time due to protocols like speedy and that new thing, meant to release http-1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser development console (cmnd+alt+I) and go to the network tab. If you cmnd+r (mac) or f5 (windows) will see the flow.

Comment: Yes, that has been said minutes before in the comments to the question. So well copied. Also this is _not_ an answer to the question, so it should have been another comment if at all.